# How did Dumbledore meet Fawkes?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, phoenix

This question is two fold.

Firstly, if a phoenix is immortal, then how was it ever born in the first place? Does a phoenix lay eggs like other birds?

Secondly, there is not much information available about Fawkes' origins and early life, except that he was a wild Phoenix until he met Dumbledore.

Where and how did Dumbledore meet Fawkes? Why is it that he was able to form such a strong bond with Fawkes? I do not recollect anything about any other witch or wizard having a phoenix as a pet.

Comment: Your question is possibly a double of [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/98774/how-did-dumbledore-gain-the-loyalty-of-fawkes).

Comment: They were in this bar and they had a few drinks and got chatting and, well, one thing led to another and before you know it, they were living together...

Comment: OMG what if they were roommates at Hogwarts? I smell a sitcom.

Comment: @Joshinder looks like you are right, but I think the first part of this question is different.